# Как поменять цвет выпадающего списка QComboBox на PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qss

У меня есть выпадающий список и я хочу чтобы он был например желтым цветом, а он наследует стиль главного окна т.е. красный, как изменить цвет самого выпадающего списка?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: red;')

        sheets = [str(i) for i in range(1, 10)]

        combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        combo.addItems(sheets)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(combo)
        self.setLayout(layout)


StyleSheet = """ 
QComboBox {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 1px 18px 1px 3px;
    min-width: 6em;
}
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    border: 2px solid darkgray;
    selection-background-color: lightgray;
}

"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно изменить стиль окна таким образом (указать имя класса для которого устанавливается стиль):

```
self.setStyleSheet('Main { background-color: red; }')
```

Тогда в StyleSheet для `QComboBox QAbstractItemView` добавьте `background-color: yellow`:

```
StyleSheet = """

QComboBox {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 1px 18px 1px 3px;
    min-width: 6em;
}
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    border: 2px solid darkgray;
    selection-background-color: lightgray;
    background-color: yellow;
}
"""
```

Также можно удалить в конструкторе стиль окна и перенести его в StyleSheet:

```
StyleSheet = """

Main {
    background-color: red;
}

QComboBox {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 1px 18px 1px 3px;
    min-width: 6em;
}
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    border: 2px solid darkgray;
    selection-background-color: lightgray;
    background-color: yellow;
}

"""
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: а подскажите как увеличить расстояние между элементами в выпадающем списке?

Comment: @Tesla это уже другой вопрос ))